# Division negative integers with xlop

Tags: xlop

I have a problem with `xlop`. Indeed, when I do

```
\opdiv[style=text,parenthesisnegative=all]{-6}{2}
```

I get -0.99999999999999 instead of -3.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) This really seems a bug in `xlop` package.

Comment: The result of division is approximate. Unfortunately, the approximation is worse when the dividend is negative.